# .NET + MySQL (or alternative SQL-based DB) a good choice?

Tags: mysql, .net, sql-server

I've been checking many articles regarding MySQL vs SQL Server, but they all relate to Web Applications. I'm now having a hard time using SQL Server with our application, since the data amount stored grows and the server slowed down badly. Apart from the database and application design, I would like to ask whether it would be a good choice to pick MySQL over SQL Server? Or maybe some other alternatives should I consider?

The reason I would like to go with MySQL is that it's free. Most of our clients use SQL Express which is quite limited on resources used and with the company growth they're unwilling to switch to SQL Standard. I believe the application and database will be re-designed soon and therefore I started thinking about MySQL.

Application I'm talking about is a desktop management system, lot's of reads and writes along with fair amount of data manipulation (for purpose of reporting).

I'm also managing new software creation in its' early stage and I was thinking whether it should use SQL Server or MySQL as well, therefore I would love to hear any opinions regarding this potential solutions, any advantages and drawbacks coming from that?

Some information that may be relevant:

- currently application uses hard-coded SQL queries, I'd like to switch
  to stored procedures
- second piece of software implements stored
  procedures
- both applications work as single-workstation software or spread over LAN network with centralized database server

Comment: This question is of topic to stackoverflow as it's answers will be primarily opinion based. My 2 cents would be to try and keep the applications blind to the particular RDBMS you choose by creating a basic data access layer that will allow you to implement data access for any RDBMS. it can be created a separate dll so that you can resuse it for different applications.

Comment: @ZoharPeled You are perfectly right : ) I work with legacy code and therefore I can't freely change it at the moment, but like I mentioned, it needs to be re-designed anyway and I am thinking about database-independent solution. The only thing that frightens me are different data types.

Comment: I don't know of any data type in sql server that can't be translated to  a .Net data type, I guess the same applies to MySql but I can't be sure since I have very little experience with this RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that MySQL can scale up more cheaply than SQL Server Express.

Both SQL Server (all editions) and MySQL require analysis and tuning as the size of your tables grows.  Your slowdown in SQL Server probably is the result of a query that doesn't have an appropriate index. That query's performance was acceptable when you had hundreds of rows in the table. Now that you have tens of thousands or more, the query is too slow. Switching to MySQL will NOT solve this problem in any magical way, but adding indexes will.

Both database systems are suitable for both web and desktop applications.

Both systems integrate well with development tools like Visual Studio and Eclipse.

You mentioned these points.

> currently application uses hard-coded SQL queries, I'd like to switch to stored procedures

The SQL Server toolchain has much better, but more costly, tools for developing and debugging stored procedures than MySQL.  Debugging SPs in MySQL is a notorious pain in the neck. It's possible to write ordinary SQL queries that are compatible, or almost compatible, between the two database systems. But it is entirely impossible to write stored procedures that run on both.

> second piece of software implements stored procedures

It's not clear what you mean by this.

> both applications work as single-workstation software or spread over LAN network with centralized database server

This affects your application installer. In the single-seat case you'll have to install your database system on the local machine along with your software.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no complex stored procedures but mainly SELECT-s and INSERT/UPDATE-s, you can use MySQL. (MySQL supports SP but in MS SQL they are more powerful). However I think that if your client's database become too big and exceed MS SQL Express limitations, it is not big expense to buy SQL Server + Windows Server.

Comment: There are actually only CRUD operations performed. My concern is about multiple subqueries/joins within MySQL, which I heard is quite slow. Buying SQL Server is not an option, since it depends on end-users which are unwilling to pay for it.

Comment: Would you mind giving my a source where I can read about MySQL SP limitations??

Comment: SP are supported in MySQL but are more advanced in MS SQL and you will save a lot of time (and nerves) if using MS SQL vs MySQL. Anyway, I think you can use MySQL for your project. BTW, Oracle has also a free version (with limitations).